Sending Audio Messages in Twilio
I’m wondering if it’s possible to send audio messages via Twilio’s API.
By “audio message” I mean the native audio recording in Apple Messages (attached) and Android messages (also attached).


Is this possible with Twilio? If not, is it possible through any platform?
Kind of in the dark and not sure where to even search, so thought I’d throw it out there in Reddit land - any advice would be appreciated!
PS - I know that I can send MMS texts, but the audio comes through as an actual mp3 file (tap on the file and it opens a media player), and not an audio recording.

Yes, it's possible. When sending audio via MMS, just make sure to use compatible media. Make the desired audio available in an accessible link. It can be through the Twilio console assets. After making the media available through a link, specify the link through the
"mediaUrl": ["https://exemplo-media.mp4"]
Supporting documentation follows.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/accepted-mime-types
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages/node

Hello @Leticia - thanks for the reply.  I believe I'm sending an accepted mime type (mp3), and it still only comes through as a file (not a playable audio message).  The user can tap on the file and open it up through Quicktime, but it does not play as native audio within the message.  Is there a difference between mp3 & mp4?

Just to keep this thread updated, I've now tested the following mime-types and all of them are delivered as files, and not "inline audio" messages: mp4, mp3, ogg, webm, mpeg, L24 and aac.  I also tried the "caf" (apple native) file but Twilio rejects this mime-type altogether.  I'm beginning to think it's not possible?
